# Controlling output placement knitr + pandoc

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown

I'm sure this has been answered before but to all my Googling abilities I can't find it. 
I want to display a number of tables in a document, with a header and/or sub header in between.

````
Section 1
--------------------------------------------------------

```{r , results='asis', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
print(xtable(summary(lm(rnorm(10)~runif(10))), caption="Table 1"), 
      caption.placement =  "top",  table.placement = "H!", 
      include.rownames=FALSE, type="latex", comment=FALSE)
```
Section 2
--------------------------------------------------------
```{r , results='asis', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
print(xtable(summary(lm(rnorm(10)~runif(10))), caption="Table 2"), 
    caption.placement = "top",  table.placement = "H!", 
    include.rownames=FALSE, type="latex", comment=FALSE)
````

```

I am finding that after knitting this *Rnw the placement is fine, but once I pandoc() it

```
knit('C:/Users/Robin/Desktop/test.rmd', 'C:/Users/Robin/Desktop/test.md') 
pandoc('C:/Users/Robin/Desktop/test.md', format='latex')
```

to produce a PDF all the images have been shoved to the bottom of the page, after both section headers. Can someone point me to an option that works, because H! in the latex code doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mb table placement should be: `table.placement = [h!]` ?

Comment: Grr!I know I beat this to death before I posted (not wanting to look completely like an idiot) but your response made me revisit it (it had been abandoned since then). 

Anyhow - it didn't like [h!], or "[h!]", but when I went back to plain old "h!" it worked just fine. I'm happy that it's working but I had to have tried "h!" before "H!". 
I switched to using Rstudio as a one-button compiler, but that's the only thing that's changed since then. Whatever works!